# how to store 18 digits in a double datatype (when numerator<denominator)

Tags: java, math

What I want to do is, for example

```
int num = 18, den = 19;
double q=(double)num/(double)den;
```

returns 0.9473684210526315

but what I want is 0.947368421052631578

since num<den, the left of the decimal point is always going to "0.", is there anyway i can use those character's space and give it to "78" instead?
if I can't do that, what would be another approach?

the reason I need this is an LC question.

Comment: `double` is already doing that - as the first bit in binary decimal representation is always 1 (to some power of 2), it is omitted.

Comment: To add to that: What you are seeing when you see 0.94.... is the output of some function that converts the binary representation of the double into a human readable _decimal_ number. The internal representation is very different, and is using all its bits in a quite efficient way.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format: "The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision (2−53 ≈ 1.11 × 10−16)". So no, you should not expect to be able to store 18 significant digits. If you need more precision than that, use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. At all.

`double` 'makes sense' in binary. A `double` uses 64-bits, therefore, by basic laws of the universe, it cannot possibly represent more than 2^64 unique numbers. With `long`, which can also represent 2^64 unique numbers, these numbers are simply 0 to 2^63-1 on the positive side and -2^63 to -1 on the negative side. But for doubles it's *way* more complicated.

You seem to think it stores 18 digits and separately, where the '.' is.

But, that wouldn't make sense. It's only "18 digits" if you represent the number in decimal (decimal = count on 10 fingers). But computers have 2 fingers; just like we modern humans tend to go: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - oh, out of fingers now, so, uh... we'll.... just start from the beginning again and add a new digit! 1..0... 10! ten!

Computers go: 0, 1.... oh, out of fingers now, so... 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001, and so on.

Now, in our decimal system, you **cannot properly represent** 1 divided by 3. Can't be done, doesn't matter how many digits you care to involve. You're forced to round it. The reason is that 3 doesn't neatly divide into 10. Imagine we were more like the ancient germanic or sumeric peoples, you don't count fingers but you count phalanxes - take your thumb, touch the top of your pointer finger, that's 1. Go down one phalanx, and keep going. For the 4th phalanx, go to the top of your middle finger. You have 12 phalanxes not on your thumb, so now you count to 12 on one hand (yes, the romans are kinda stupid, this system is so much better) You'll have to make up a symbol for the digit '10' (we decimal counters don't have such a digit, 9 is our last. They have 2 more. Let's call them A and B for 10 and 11). In their system, 1/3 can be written as 0.4.

For the same reason, something like 1/5, which works great in decimal (That's simply 0.2), **cannot be perfectly represented in binary** - for the same reason 1/3 can't in decimal.

That should hopefully explain why none of your thinking is going to work out. You just can't trouble `double` that way - as 'its a bunch of digits and a dot someplace'.

The obvious way to go here is to use `BigDecimal` which works exactly as you want (it's any amount of digits - as many as you want. hundreds of thousands is fine), and a number representing 'where is the dot'). However, it's *considerably* larger in memory load than a `double`, so if that's the reason, you're in trouble. Hopefully its not.

A worse alternative would be to represent your number as a `long`, with your code knowing that e.g. long value `947368421052631578` means `0.947368421052631578` which is not an easy operation to perform, and cannot be done with `double` math (because `0.947368421052631578` in in decimal is not going to work in binary, it'll be endless just like 1/3 is).